# Sphinx errors "expected token" not found all of a sudden

Tags: sphinx

I've been editing a large sphinx config file that contains several different indexes I can modify/rotate, generally I do not rotate all.

All of a sudden I got

```
ERROR: section contents: expected token, got '=' in /home/indexer/sphinx.conf.php line 3830 col 1.
```

I am using winscp to edit so tried ctrl-g 3830 to find it and it tells me it is an invalid line #.  I thought perhaps I messed something up in the index I was working on so tried to rotate each of the other indexes but got the same error. How can I possibly trouble-shoot the error

Comment: The .php extension suggests maybe a dynamic config file? If so look at the line in the output, not the script itself.

Comment: @BarryHunter Yeah realized yesterday I had to look at the php not the config file itself. Brute forced it by taking back-up cfg and existing one into text difference tool to find out what had changed